# SQL INNER JOIN automatic optimization in HSQLDB

Tags: sql, optimization, hsqldb

The execution speed of the following queries is dramatically different. The second one finishes orders of magnitude faster than the first one.

```
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.X=B.Y WHERE B.Z=1
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM B) ON A.X=B.Y WHERE B.Z=1
```

It would be great if someone would write why this is.
The database is `HSQLDB` with `JDBC`.

Additional information: Version of `HSQLDB` is 2.3.2. And column A.X is indexed but column B.Y is not.

Comment: Can you test a third version: `SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.X=B.Y AND B.Z=1`?

Comment: @JoëlSalamin This has around the same execution time as the first slow version.

Comment: It may be caused by the fact that `B.Y` isn't indexed. Can you try this other version and tell me if there is a performance gain/loss: `SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.Z = 1) ON A.X=B.Y`

Comment: @JoëlSalamin this behaves about the same as the second example in the opening post. Yes, but probably it has something to do with the indexing. I just do not understand in what way this would be.

Comment: How big is your table `B`?

Comment: @JoëlSalamin It has got around 5000 rows and 10 columns. Of course, indexing B.Y is a good idea, but this is not the issue of the question. I am interested in how HSQLDB treats the two examples differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: `indexing`

Imagine that I have a dictionary and someone gives me a task to find 5000 words in it. This task would take me several hours.
But now imagine that this dictionary is unsorted. It would take me years to find all these words in it.
Computer is faster and for first task it needs only miliseconds while second task remains several seconds.

**Why is the first query so slow?**

This is because there is `INNER JOIN` and it is done on unindexed column.

**Why is the second query so fast?**

This is because there is subquery. This subquery is materialized into temporary table and index is created for join column. So you are not joining now with unindexed B table but with indexed temporary table. HSQLDB creates this indexing on temporary table to make it easier to join. Even if you change join condition to more complex (for example: `A.X = B.Y + 2*B.Z`) this query will still be fast. This means that HSQLDB creates index on expression used in join condition.

Comment: This definitely makes sense. Do you maybe have any reference for what you described?